# Variable changing for no reason

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to create my own Adapter. Each time the adapter calls getView, this code is executed:

```
private String readDatabaseValue(String id)
    {
        id = id.replace("-", "").toLowerCase();
        int index = id.indexOf("fr");
        final String nb = id.substring(index + 2);
        String sub = id.replace(nb, "") ;

        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference(sub).child(nb);

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                message = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                if (message == null)
                    Log.d("MESSAGE1", nb + " is null");
                else
                    Log.d("MESSAGE1", message);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        if (message == null)
            Log.d("MESSAGE2", id + " is null");
        else
            Log.d("MESSAGE2", message);

        return message;
    }
```

But, MESSAGE1 sometimes give me the right message, while MESSAGE2 always return null.
So why is a change happening?
(message is a global variable)

Comment: This shouldn't compile. You have a return statement outside of any method. Please show your full code as a [mcve]

Comment: @cricket_007 I updated my code. Thanks for your help, but how should I do to get this working?

Comment: You'll need to propagate the callback pattern up the calltree - so think of `readDatabaseValue` as initiating the read and add a callback parameter which is invoked in `onDataChange`.

Comment: `message` is not a global variable, since Java doesn't have global variables. You presumably mean it is a field of the class. It will not have been set to anything yet when you log it, which is why it is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not changing "for no reason".

Your return statement probably happens *before* message1 is even assigned (and returns null} because Firebase requires a network call and will be *delayed*.

The fact that you're assigning "a global variable" within a callback is generally a bad pattern (nothing is being notified that the value is changing). It's not clear how your message is used in your view, but you need to instead pass through a callback, as Andy mentions in the comments

For example, define some interface

```
public interface Callback<T> {
    void onMessage(T message);
}
```

Then add that as a parameter

```
void readDatabaseValue(String id, final Callback<String> cb) {
   ... 
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            message = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            cb.onMessage(message);
        }
    });
    return; // for demonstration purposes 
}
```

Then pass it where you lookup the value

```
// do not declare message variable outside of here 
readDatabaseValue(id, new Callback<String>() {
    @Override 
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        // value is returned here, and you're welcome to pass it on to other methods 
    } 
});
// do not try to access a message variable here, it will be null
```

Comment: It certainly is not a global variable since there is no such thing in Java.

Comment: Eh. Just writing what was in the question

Answer (score 0):

The `addValueEventListener` is called everytime a new `View` object is constructed, so
you have to include the `MESSAGE2` processing in the `onDataChange` callback as well.